# Retrieve values from class: custom methods or reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

for take values ​​from a class where there are only primitive fields (no methods) as a list of key - value do you prefer use reflection (with a dynamic iteration) or a specific method that return an HashMap? What do you prefer?

At this moment there are fifty classes or so but probably in the future they can grow to another twenty or thirty (in regime)

I like reflection but in this case probably is not necessary?

Comment: I assume you ask this since you can't modify the classes and these fields are marked as `private`, right?

Comment: hi, fields are marked like public but i need to write a generic parser to get all key-value for these classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reflection-based approach is cleaner, because it does not require your classes to implement additional methods, and you would not be liable to maintain these methods when new fields are added to existing classes.

A `HashMap`-based approach does not buy you much in terms of performance, because primitives must be wrapped in objects to be inserted into the map - the same way they would be wrapped to be returned from the reflection-based calls.

Comment: i think that reflection is cleaner and is better maintainable, but why is necessary a wrap in object? i can fill an HashMap like this : HashMap hm = new HashMap();
         hm.put("field1", 10d);
         hm.put("field2", 10f);
         hm.put("field3", 'a');
         hm.put("field4", (long)100);

... is right? have similar performances?

Comment: @mrddter The reason why you can call `hm.put("field1", 10d)` is [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html): Java compiler wraps the value for you. This feature was added in Java 5 to make type-erased generics usable.

Comment: got it! initially when autoboxing came out I was doubtful.. so autoboxing has comparable performance to the reflection? this is a good point for decide which way is better

Comment: @mrddter It's not autoboxing vs. reflection, my point was that since both the reflection APIs and hash map use autoboxing, which is much slower than using primitives directly, the advantages of using a hash map over reflection in terms of performance are not that great. You'd get a somewhat faster program with the hash map, but that would come at the price of a potential maintenance nightmare.